# Symmetric matrix with different eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $ A\in \mathbb{R}^{2,2} $ a symmetric matrix with different eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and $ v_1 $ the eigenvector of the eigenvalue $ \lambda_1 $.

Show: If $ v $ is orthogonal to $ v_1 $ then $ v $ is the eigenvector of $ A $ of the eigenvalue $ \lambda_2 $.

My Idea:

Let be $ A\in \mathbb{R}^{2,2} $ a symmetric matrix with different eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and $ v_1 $ the eigenvector of the eigenvalue $ \lambda_1 $. For all $ v\in \mathbb{R}^2 $ with $ 
v_1^T\cdot v=0 $ we get
$$ \begin{align}&(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\cdot v_1^T\cdot v=0\\[15pt]\Leftrightarrow \quad &v_1^T\cdot A\cdot v=\lambda_1\cdot v_1^T\cdot v=\lambda_2\cdot v_1^T\cdot v=v_1^T\cdot \lambda_2\cdot v \\[15pt]\Leftrightarrow \quad &v_1^T\cdot \underbrace{(A-\lambda_2\cdot I_2)\cdot v}_{=(*)}=0\end{align}$$

Now I would like to show that $ (*)=0 $ but I don't have any idea how I could do this.

Comment: Fact: symmetric matrices are diagonalizable with the eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues being orthogonal (see Jochens answer below). A $2 \times 2$ matrix where we already have a one-dimensional eigenspace for $\lambda_1$ then doesn't leave much choice left for the second eigenvector. Maybe this helps you...

Answer (score 1):

$v_2$ is the eigenvector of $\lambda_2$, then
$$\lambda_2\langle v_1, v_2\rangle=\langle v_1, Av_2\rangle \overset{(*)}{=}\langle  Av_1,v_2\rangle=\lambda_1\langle v_1, v_2\rangle.$$
At the star, you need $A$ to be symmetric. Hence, we get
$$(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\cdot \langle v_1,v_2\rangle =0. $$
Since $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ we get $ \langle v_1,v_2\rangle =0$. Observe, that $H:=(\operatorname{span}\{v_1\})^{\bot}:=\{w:\langle v_1,w\rangle=0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, because from $\langle v_1, u\rangle =  0$ and $\langle v_1,w \rangle =  0$ follows $\langle v_1, u+\mu w \rangle =  0$. Its dimension is at least 1, since $v_2\in H$ and $v_2\neq 0$. Its dimension is less than 2, since $v_1\notin H$, because $\langle v_1,v_1\rangle \neq 0$. Hence, its dimension is exactly 1.

Let $u\neq 0$ such that $H=\operatorname{span}\{u\}$.  Because $\langle v_1,v\rangle =\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=0$, we have $v,v_2\in H$, i.e. there are $\mu_1,\mu_2\in \mathbb R$ with $v=\mu_1 u$ and $v_2=\mu_2 u$. This yields $\mu_2 v = \mu_1\mu_2 u=\mu_1v_2$.

Comment: You should add that you need the symmetry, or "self-adjoint"-ness of $A$ to make the second and third equalities hold

Comment: Hello :) Thank you. I've added now.

Comment: "where v2 is the eigenvector of λ2" But I have to show that. Or what are you doing?

Comment: Hello hallo97 :) I show, if $v_2$ is an eigenvector to an eigenvalue diffenrent from $\lambda_1$, then $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle=0$. You're right, it is left to show, that $v$ is a multiple of $v_2$. Can you show, that from $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle=\langle v_1, v\rangle=0$ follows that $v$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent. You have to use, that we are in $\mathbb R^2$. It means the orthogonal complement of an one dimensional subspace is one dimensional.

Comment: I've added it. Thank you :)

Comment: No. You just showed that both eigenvectors $ v_1,v_2  $ are orthogonal. But I don't see why you can see it inverted now. A linear combination of $ v_2 $ is just special case but what if it's not the case?

Comment: I don't get your problem. Maybe let's try again. The space $(\operatorname{span}\{v_1\})^{\bot}=\{w:\langle v_1,w\rangle=0\}$ is one dimensional, right? It means, there is a $u\neq 0$, such that $(\operatorname{span}\{v_1\})^{\bot}=\operatorname{span}\{u\}$. Since $v,v_2\in (\operatorname{span}\{v_1\})^{\bot}$, there are $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ with $v=\mu_1 u$ and $v_2=\mu_2 u$. Hence, $\mu_2 v=\mu_1\mu_2 u =\mu_1 v_2$.

Comment: "...is one dimensional, right?" To be honest: Why??

Comment: Because the dimension of $\mathbb R^2$ is 2 and the dimension of $\operatorname{v}_1$ is 1, we get $2-1=1$.

Is it clear, that $(\operatorname{span}\{v_1\})^\bot$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$? From $\langle v_1, u\rangle =  0$ and $\langle v_1,w \rangle =  0$ follows $\langle v_1, u+\mu w \rangle =  0$.

What dimension does it have?. It contains $v_2$, so its dimension is at least 1. It doesn't contain $v_1$, so its dimension is less than 2.

Comment: I watched in my notes and I forgot the fact that $ W^{\perp}\oplus W=V $ and $ \dim(V)=\dim(W^{\perp})+\dim(W) $ ($ W\subseteq V $ is subspace from $ V $). So here I get $ 2=\dim(\mathbb{R}^2)=\dim((span(v_1))^{\perp})+\dim(span(v_1))=\dim((span(v_1))^{\perp})+1.$My further chain of thoughts: We get from the last equation $ \dim((span(v_1))^{\perp})=1 $. Now let be $ v\in \mathbb{R}^2 $ arbitrary with $ \langle v_1,v\rangle=0. $ Because of $ \dim((span(v_1))^{\perp})=1 $ we have $ v,v_2\in (span(v_1))^{\perp} $. So $ v,v_2 $ are linear dependent.

Comment: lucky you :D Then no more questions are unanswered?

Comment: Yes, I don't really like the concept of orthogonal complements, or in my linear algebra course we didn't go deep enough on it for theoretical applications / assignments ... But that one little thing that I forgot was blocking my brain.